# C# Visual Studio 2012 White Sidebar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual studio 2012 with dark theme, and I have a white sidebar which i would like to hide or change color to darker one. Here is the image with sidebar so you can see about what

[image]

Comment: Have you have tried switching back and forth between light and dark themes? Also you might try disabling any add-ons that might be screwing you up.

Answer (score 5):

That is the indicator margin which you can change the color of under Tools|Options.  Then under Environment|Fonts and Colors.  Go to the Indicator Margin display item.  You can change the background color there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) extension then you can set the value to whatever color you'd like. First open the editor by selecting the `Tools->Customize Colors` menu. Mouse over your custom theme (create one if you haven't yet) and choose `Edit Theme`. Select the `Show All Elements` icon at the top and search for 'Indicator'. Edit the color of `Text Editor -> Indicator Margin -> Background` and click the `Save and Apply' icon.